# Centered inline logo option issue on wordpress divi 3.0 theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have some issues on my wordpress site.
I used divi 3.0 theme for my website.
Then there is a issues, so I am trying to fix it.
On header there is a logo and six menus.
It looks good on mozilla and Chrome but not good on safari.
Please check the following site, and please let me know what is the reason.
http://jane.devocm.com 
Thank you

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that the centered-inline-logo-wrap has an inline style="width: 416px;" Did you add this? Safari isn't showing the inline style on that element like chrome is. Is there a different way you could apply this? To the class instead of the element directly?

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Then how can I add style="width: 416px;"?
where can I add this code?
would you let me know about this?
Thank you

Comment: You want to add it to this class .centered-inline-logo-wrap either the width, or a margin left and right to it. I've used divi once before, a long time ago, there should be a place to enter custom css somewhere.